# Nextjs getStaticPaths and getStaticProps unable to fetch dockerized API endpoints while building the app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, build

Currently migrating a small React app to a more appropriate - scalable solution with Next framework brought me to wonder if I misunderstood Next's ISR feature. This app is supporting a "cine-club" activity, and amongst other features, specific movie pages for each recommended movie.

My project stack is a containerized application with :

- A postgres db
- A pgAdmin instance
- A dedicated backend API (Fastify)
- A next app
- A nginx reverse-proxy / http server
- A certbot routine container

Each in their own dedicated containers, orchestrated with docker-compose.

**Goal :** I wanted to use ISR in order to pre-render each movie page at build time.
**Problem :** During docker-compose orchestrated build time and build time only, back-end provided movie information can't be reached, leading to an aborted pre-building phase. In dev mode, everything works, in production mode, pages are rendered without any problem.
When build is launched directly from the console of the Nextjs app container, it works flawlessly.
**versions :** docker-compose 3, node 18.12, Next 13.1.2, React 18.2.0

**docker-compose.yml** (focused on what we need)

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: ./data
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5431:80
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app_network

  api:
    hostname: cinevoraces_api
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    # links:
    #   - postgres
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3005:3005
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
    networks:
      - app_network

  app:
    hostname: cinevoraces_app
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - app_network
```

**app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:19-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./

# building the app
RUN npm i
RUN npm run build

# Running the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**app/.env.local** (shortened)

```
API_BASE_URL_CSR=http://localhost:3005
API_BASE_URL_SSR=http://cinevoraces_api:3005
```

**app/next.config.js** (shortened)

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL_CSR: process.env.API_BASE_URL_CSR,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL_SSR: process.env.API_BASE_URL_SSR,
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**app/pages/films/[film].tsx** focused on getStaticPaths & getStaticProps

```
export const getStaticPaths: ()=>Promise<{ paths: { params: {} }[]; fallback: boolean | string } | []> = async () => {
  try {
    const movies = await getRequestSSR('/movies?where[is_published]=true');
    const paths = movies.map((movie: MinimalMovie) => ({ params: { film: '' + movie.id } }));
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: true,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return {
      paths: [],
      fallback: true,
    };;
  }
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<FilmProps, Params> = async (context) => {
  const { film: id } = context.params!;
  try {
    const result = await getRequestSSR(`/movies?where[id]=${id}` + selectQueryString);
    if (result.message === 'Aucun film trouvé') throw new Error(result.message);
    return {
      props: {
        movies: result,
        revalidate: 60,
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
};
```

**app/binder/SSRBinder.ts** (outsourced fetching logic)

```
import handleResponse from './handleResponse';

const baseUrlSSR = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL_SSR;

/**
 * Generic function for SSR & ISR data fetching
 * @param endpoint string
 * @returns response payload
 */
export const getRequestSSR = async (endpoint: string) => {
  if (baseUrlSSR) {
    const res = await fetch(baseUrlSSR + endpoint);
    return handleResponse(res, endpoint);
  }
};
```

handleResponse is just a dedicated function built to deal with misc StatusCodes returned by the API (included handmade token refreshing logic). It returns, if the request succeeded, its body.

**With docker-compose, I can just catch a glimse of the error message in my VSCode console :**

```
errno: -3008
code: 'ENOTFOUND'
syscall: 'getaddrinfo'
hostname: 'cinevoraces_api'
```

I initially thought it was a data availability matter, so I tried to build and up each container manually and that did not worked as expected.

I tried replacing host_name by localhost, multiple docker-compose network configurations, hardcoding fetched urls.

Then I ran the build from the inside of the app container, and it worked !
**Output from the docker container "app" after build :**
[build final logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT52t.png)

I feel like I cornered the issue beeing on a approximative use of docker or docker-compose network feature, but I'm still unable to put my finger on it. Why is it working in dev and production mode, but not during build time ?

As I'm quite new to development, I know my code and use of these multiple tools can be approximative, so feel free to add extra pieces of advice.

Thank you for all the help you'll provide :)

Comment: Hey Yves, did you solve this? I run in the exact same problem :-)

Comment: Hey !
I didn't, I did a temporary workaround rebuilding the app from the container.

I will update the complete app to Next latest version, hopefully I could solve this curiousity.